# onResume() of fragment gets called before onDestroy() of activity when coming back from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I have an issue while calling activity from fragment. I am calling an activity from a fragment so that the activity opens as a new window in the device by using the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now when I press the back button from the NewActivity, The previous fragment gets opened. It is working fine. But I need to perform some tasks in the onDestroy() of the NewActivity before onResume of the fragment is called. But here the onResume() of the fragment gets called first before the OnDestroy() the activity gets called.

Can anybody tell why this happens?

Comment: because the fragment loads firsts and then the activity is destroyed at the back. if the activity was destroyed first, then the fragment wont be called at all. what you can do is, that before the statement that calls the fragment, call a function that does all the things that you are doing in Destroy. so your tasks will be performed and then the fragment will be called.

Comment: @aradhna thanks for the comment. I called onBackPressed() method and finished the activity from there and wrote all the stuff there. Its working fine now.